# Can Copper Fungicide be used on an apple tree with fruit already growing?

Tags: fruit-trees, fungus, apples

I was wondering if its possible to cover the growing apples with a plastic bag while I spray the leaves with this Copper Fungicide. I read somewhere that your not supposed to spray the Copper Fungicide if fruit is already growing.

[image: I have an apple growing with the surrounding leaves covered in orange spots]

[image: Copper Fungicide]

I came here to ask the same question and found this duplicate. Since it hasn't gotten any attention, I'll expand it. I have a tree looking a lot like this picture. I too heard something about not using copper once there's fruit. I realize that the very best treatment is to have done things before now—dormant oil, copper when leaves are just emerging, etc. But I wonder what, if anything, I can do about these cedar rust spots during the summer. Of these statements, which are true and which are false?

- Sure, spray copper now; it will help.
- Don't spray copper now; it will hurt in some way. (Poison the fruit, cause russeting, etc.)
- Don't *bother* spraying copper now; it won't have any effect this late in the game.
- Apply some other treatment.
- Ignore it for now. Treat with copper next early spring, but in the meantime, the damage is done for this year and as long as you're not losing leaves, leave it alone.
- Strip the affected leaves. (Related question: how much is too much? what if it's all the leaves?)

Comment: Stackexchange is a place. A question asked three years ago gets edited and has a bounty. Anyway, with all chemicals of this type, read that label carefully before use.

Comment: Bounty has expired, I have 24 hours to award it to an answer. Really, nobody's got anything?